# SVN Commit Error in NetBeans

Tags: svn, netbeans

I am trying to use SVN in Netbeans. I installed Plug-in Successfully but it seems that the SVN error, in my case is related to the project structure.

I had the latest version of the cient, but still received this error. Now I can Import project from SVN and also Export it..But Problem is only in Commit.

> `org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Unsupported working
>   copy format This client is too old to work with working copy
>   'C:\Users\riddhi.barbhaya\Desktop\GaugeExample'.  You need to get a
>   newer Subversion client, or to downgrade this working copy. See
>   http://subversion.tigris.org/faq.html#working-copy-format-change for
>   details.
>
> We strongly recommend to either install a newer Subversion client or
>   downgrade your working copy. Any local changes might corrupt your
>   working copy and some file operations as copying, renaming and
>   deleting will not work correctly.`

Please Help me..Thanks..

Comment: The message is pretty explicit. Just download a supported version of SVN. As the message say, you will need to version > 1.5.0. This is the version used by the latest version of Netbeans.

Comment: @nathan..I Edited now my Error Message..Please Go Through it..and Please help if you have any Idea.

Answer (score 1):

Use only 1 client to check-out your working copy (the plugin in netbeans), this assures that you have a working copy format that the client understands.

You can also additionally install other svn clients, but they must use the same working copy format. [TortoiseSVN  downloads](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tortoisesvn/files/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer..I am using only 1 client..and I know about Tortoise SVN..I can import project from SVN but From I can not commit my code..and I Edited now my Error Message..Please Go Through it..and Please help me..If you have any Idea..

Comment: The working copy you checked out, has a different format as the svn client that is doing the commit. You really should only use *one* client, this assures that you have the correct version. What is the version of your netbeans plugin? it seems to be using http://svnkit.com/, but maybe not the latest version.